# Reading the values from parameter store using AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services

I am trying to retrieve the value from amazon parameterstore using AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient. I installed AWSSDK.SimpleSystemsManagement in my asp.net application. I wrote this code in my class:

```
    using Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement;
    using Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model;

    var request = new GetParameterRequest()
                {
                    Name = "/CleanArchitectureAppWebApi/postgresconnection"
                };
    
                using (var client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-west-2")))
                {
                    var response = client.GetParameterAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    // connectionString = response.Parameter.Value;
                }
```

I keep getting an error on this line saying "the type AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient exists in both AWSSDK.simplesystemsManagement". I am not sure why this error is coming. I tried to prefix this line:

```
 using (var client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-west-2")))

like this:

using (var client = new Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient(RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-west-2")))
```

the error is still not going away. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: `in both AWSSDK.simplesystemsManagement` and .... - in both what and what? I think you may have a version mismatch somewhere in your NuGet packages causing a conflict - can you please update your Q with the NuGet packages you have for this project? `.csproj` or `packages.config` will have it :)

Comment: Also: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the proper package using NuGET? I executed this .NET code:

```
using Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement;
using Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model;
...

 var client = new AmazonSimpleSystemsManagementClient();

  var request = new GetParameterRequest()
   {
       Name = "RDSConnection"
  };

  var response = client.GetParameterAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

  Console.WriteLine("Parameter value is " + response.Parameter.Value);
```

Result was successful:

[image]

Comment: I think OP said "I installed AWSSDK.SimpleSystemsManagement in my asp.net application." - it'd be good to see the `using` statements you have though!

Comment: using Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement;
using Amazon.SimpleSystemsManagement.Model;